# Perl hash containing multiple arrays

Tags: perl

Normally I can wrap my mind around all the different complexities of hashes and arrays, but I just cannot seem to get this working...

Here is my array:

```
$event['date'] = $my_date;
$event['machine'] = $my_machine;
```

Here is what I want my hash to look like

```
$User{$name}{'allowed'} = 52;
$User{$name}{'denied'} = 4;
$User{$name}{'events'}[] = @event;
```

I need to loop through each user (which currently works) and then within that user loop through each event.

2 Questions:

1. How do I add multiple instances of the event array to my hash?
2. How do I loop through those arrays?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An array in Perl has the following properties:

- It is indexed by a continuous range of positive integers, starting with `0`.
- It holds scalars as values
- They are indexed with square brackets, e.g. `$array[0] = $val`.

A hash on the other hand has the properties

- It is indexed by unique strings.
- The key-value pairs have no guaranteed order.
- It holds scalars as values.
- They are indexed with curlies, e.g. `$hash{"some key"} = $val`. If the key is a valid identifier, the quotes are optional: `$hash{some_key} = $val`.

Neither hashes nor arrays are scalars, but you can take a reference with the unary `\` operator, which then is a scalar.

Do not get confused by other languages using the name “associative array” for what Perl calls hashes, or by having the same syntax for hashes and arrays.

For your event data structure, you want a hash as well:

```
my %event = (
  date    => $my_date,
  machine => $my_machine,
);
...;
$User{$name}{events} = \%event; # see the reference operator.
```

If you want the user to have multiple events, you want to use that entry as an array reference, and push the `\%event` onto the end:

```
push @{ $User{$name}{events} }, \%event;
```

The `@{ ... }` takes an array reference and *dereferences* it to an array.

#### Using the data structure

Given a hash, you can loop through the keys like

```
for my $key (keys %hash) { ... }
```

Given a hashref, we have to dereference it first:

```
for my $key (keys %{ code_producing_hashref() }) { ... }
```

Given an array reference, we have to dereference it before looping over it:

```
for my $value (@{ code_producing_arrayref() }) { ... }
```

So for example to loop over each event, we could do

```
for my $user (keys %User) {
  say "User $user has the following events:";
  for my $event (@{ $User{$user}{events} }) {
    say "date=$event->{date} machine=$event->{machine}";
  }
}
```

The `$hashref->{$key}` syntax accesses the field in a hashref. It works like `my %hash = %$hashref; $hash{$key}`, except without the needless copy.

#### Further reading

Perl references can be confusing, and the syntax is downright ugly. I recommend reading the documentation for a better understanding:

1. [`perlreftut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)
2. [`perlref`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html)
3. [`perldsc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much for not just the examples but also the reasoning.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if I get you right completely.

What you describe as "my array" looks more like a hash `%event` because you are using names, not indizes. So let's assume the following.

You have events, each event is a hash `%event` and is defined like:

```
my %event;
$event{date} = $my_date;
$event{machine} = $my_machine;
```

Note that you can omit quotes on simple hash keys. Now if you have defined several events like that, say `%event1`, `%event2` and so on, you add them to an array. You have to add references to those event-hashes!

```
my @events = ( \%event1, \%event2 );
```

Now your user-hash events should be defined like that:

```
$user{$name}{events} = [ @events ];
```

Again here, you need to set the events of a user to a reference to an array. The contents will be what your event list contains. This will basically copy the elements of `@events` to your user object. You could also write it like

```
$user{$name}{events} = \@events;
```

but then you are referencing the `@events` array directly.

Now looping is very easy.

```
foreach my $name (@names) {
    foreach my $event (@{$user{$name}{events}}) {
        # do something with $event
    }
}
```

I'm dereferencing the events-array with `@{ ... }` to get a simple list of events in `$event`.

Answer (score 0):

### How do I add multiple instances of the event array to my hash?

Build an abstraction to add an event.

```
sub add_event {
  my($user,$name,$event) = @_;

  push @{ $user->{$name}{events} }, $event;
}
```

In practice, calls to it resemble

```
add_event \%User, "MasterZ", { date => $^T, machine => "host1" };
```

### How do I loop through those arrays?

Another abstraction will be helpful here too.

```
use Storable qw/ dclone /;

sub all_events {
  my($user,$name) = @_;

  my $clone = dclone $user->{$name}{events};
  wantarray ? @$clone : $clone;
}
```

The call to [`dclone`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Storable) performs a [deep copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy#Deep_copy), which makes the return value safe to pass to outsiders with no fear that they will modify your internal data.

Use it as in

```
foreach my $event (all_events $name) {
  # do stuff with $event->{date} and $event->{machine} 
}
```

### Complete example

With the following code

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Storable qw/ dclone /;

sub add_event {
  my($user,$name,$event) = @_;

  push @{ $user->{$name}{events} }, $event;
}

sub all_events {
  my($user,$name) = @_;

  my $clone = dclone $user->{$name}{events};
  wantarray ? @$clone : $clone;
}

my %User = ( MasterZ => { allowed => 52, denied => 4 } );

add_event \%User, "MasterZ", { date => $^T,     machine => "host1" };
add_event \%User, "MasterZ", { date => $^T + 1, machine => "host2" };

for (all_events \%User, "MasterZ") {
  my($date,$machine) = @{$_}{qw/ date machine /};
  print "$date - $machine\n";
}

# show the internal layout of %User
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Indent = $Data::Dumper::Terse = 1;
print Dumper \%User;
```

the output will be similar to

```
1371671154 - host1
1371671155 - host2
{
  'MasterZ' => {
    'allowed' => 52,
    'events' => [
      {
        'date' => '1371671154',
        'machine' => 'host1'
      },
      {
        'date' => 1371671155,
        'machine' => 'host2'
      }
    ],
    'denied' => 4
  }
}
```